# How to disable a radiobuttonlist using Java Script in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created a web form in which I have take certain fields like Name, Age and two radio button list (Required and ID). I want to enable disable certain fields on the value of one radiobutton list "Required". The "Required" Radiobuttonlist has two items, "YES", "NO". If I select yes, then certain fields should get enabled disabled and vice versa.

I am able to disable the texboxes, however I am not able to disable a radiobutton list "ID" which has to list items in it as taxId and PAN. I have used the following code for it

```
function EnableDisableID() {

        if (document.getElementById("<%=rdID.ClientID %>") != null) {

            var IDList = document.getElementById('<%= rdID.ClientID  %>');


            var isOpenID;

            if (IDList != null) {

                var openSubID = IDList.getElementsByTagName("input");

                for (var i = 0; i < openSubID.length; i++) {

                    if (openSubID[i].checked) {

                        openSubID = openSubID[i].value;
                     }
                }
            }
            if (openSubID == 'true') {                    
                document.getElementById('<%=fbo1RadioButtonList.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtFbo1TaxId.ClientID %>').disabled = false;

            }
            if (isOpenSubAccount == 'false') {

                alert("Printing..." + isOpenSubAccount);
                document.getElementById('<%=fbo1RadioButtonList.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtFbo1TaxId.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to disable the FBO1TaxId, however, I am not able to disable the radiobutton list "fbo1RadioButtonList". How will I achieve it. do I have to treat its value individually?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I played with my code just a bit and came to a solution below:

```
function EnableDisableTaxID() {

        if (document.getElementById("<%=rdOpeningSubAccount.ClientID %>") != null) {

            var openSubAccountList = document.getElementById('<%= rdOpeningSubAccount.ClientID  %>');
            var rdFbo1TaxId = document.getElementById('<%=fbo1RadioButtonList.ClientID %>');
            var rdFBO1Items = rdFbo1TaxId.getElementsByTagName('input'); 

            var isOpenSubAccount;

            if (openSubAccountList != null) {

                var openSubAccount = openSubAccountList.getElementsByTagName("input");

                for (var i = 0; i < openSubAccount.length; i++) {

                    if (openSubAccount[i].checked) {

                        isOpenSubAccount = openSubAccount[i].value;                            
                    }
                }
            }               
            if (isOpenSubAccount == 'true') {
                for (var i = 0; i < rdFBO1Items.length; i++) {
                    rdFBO1Items[i].disabled = false; 
                }        
               document.getElementById('<%=txtFbo1TaxId.ClientID %>').disabled = false;

            }
            if (isOpenSubAccount == 'false') {

                for (var i = 0; i < rdFBO1Items.length; i++) {
                    rdFBO1Items[i].disabled = true;
                }                     
                document.getElementById('<%=txtFbo1TaxId.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over the radio buttons and disable each one. If your buttons are in a form, and you have a reference to the form, then you can use the common name for the buttons to get a collection. Loop over the collection and set each button's `disabled` property.

If you might either enable or disable the buttons, you can use a condition to set the value, something like:

```
var rbuttons = form.radioName;
var disabled = true;   // disables buttons, set to false to enable

for (var i=0, iLen=rbuttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  rbuttons[i].disabled = disabled;
}
```

To enable the buttons, set the `disabled` variable to false.